# Add View dialog missing from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, mvc

In Visual Studio 2012 I use to be able to write a new controlled method, right click on it and create the view automatically.

In Visual Studio 2013 I can't seem to do this anymore.

How can I easily create a new view in 2013?

**EDIT:** I don't have VS2012 installed anymore, but [here is an example](http://www.rapidprogramming.com/tutorial/Dot-Net-NET-MVC-MVC4-Add-a-View-in-Visual-Studio-2012-893) I found online:
[image]

Here's what it currently looks like in VS2013:
[image]

As you can see "Add View" is no longer an option.

Comment: can you show us an example of what you mean in 2012?

Answer (score 0):

This was in the preview version of Visual Studio 2013. I've since installed the RTM version and the option has returned.